# TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python

```
seniornames =[]
paidornot =[]
for i in range("senior"):
 print("Please enter the name of the Senior Citizen", i+1);
 seniornames.append (input())
 print(seniornames)
```

there is an error saying -  File "/Users/rheasethi/Documents/Task 2 pre release.py", line 37, in 
    for i in range("senior"):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

What should I do?

Comment: What do you expect `range("senior")` to do? `range` takes an integer and returns a range up to that integer. `range(5)` being `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, `range("senior")` is…? (If you have a *variable* called `senior` and would like to pass it instead of a string, that’s `range(senior)`, but that information isn’t in your question so it’s just a guess.)

Comment: for i in range("senior"):
 print("Please enter the name of the Senior Citizen", i+1);       /// range() can only be used with intger ..'

Answer (score 0):

[range(start, stop[, step])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

> The arguments must be **plain integers**. If the step argument is omitted,
>   it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0.

From `i+1`,it seems that you need i to be an integer,so maybe what you want is this:

```
seniornames =[]
paidornot =[]
for i in range(len("senior")):
    print("Please enter the name of the Senior Citizen", i+1)
    seniornames.append (input())
    print(seniornames)
```

Or

```
for i in range(5):
    print("Please enter the name of the Senior Citizen", i+1)
    seniornames.append (input())
    print(seniornames)
```